# Database design for user profile software

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

Im working in a University project in which I have to design a database for a software portfolio management web application. When a new user joins the company, and according to his profile, a list of software will be installed on his machine. But I can't figure out what's the best way to approach this problem

So far I have come up with this schema. how can I solve this? Any help would be much appreciated :)

[image]

Comment: Can't judge a schema without seeing the `SELECTs` that will hit it.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of your problem, you are looking at it from a historical point of view - "What software has a user got, and what profile are they part of". You need to turn this on its head and assign all the software that goes with a profile, then simply assign the person to the profile. They will then get all the software associated with the profile.

So in your example SoftwareUsers is replaced by SoftwareProfile, and away you go.